# Spark - Read parquet files from multiple locations efficiently

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I am trying to read multiple paths from azure storage account. We have mounted the container in databricks to /mnt/dataMount.

The paths are in a list.

```
var path = List("/mnt/datalakeMount/path1/path2/123.parquet","/mnt/datalakeMount/path3/path4/245.parquet")
val read = spark.read.parquet(path: _*)
```

This throws below error but the path and the file exists.

```
Path does not exist: dbfs:/mnt/datalakeMount/path1/123.parquet;
```

Any other way to read multiple files? Sometimes we may need to read 20000 folders and sometimes just 1 folder. So trying to find any good solution other partition discovery option in Spark

Comment: So does it work if you try to read 1 file? Also, it's probably just a typo but the path from your error message is not present in the list from your example.

Comment: It would help to give a short linux tree command list of what you're trying to solve. It's possible that you only need a wildcard `*` in the file path.